# Nginx configuration for multiple domains and same application

Tags: nginx, tomcat, tomcat8

I have the following scenario:

A single application that will serve several different domains, on a single server, and a single context of a single Tomcat instance. (The DNS of all domains are configured and functional)

That is, I need it when the browser points to the address:

`domain1.example` >> redirect to >> http://127.0.0.1/websiteapp

`domain2.example` >> redirect to >> http://127.0.0.1/websiteapp

`domainn.com.br` >> redirect to >> http://127.0.0.1/websiteapp

In the application it is retrieved (via request URL) the calling domain, that is, it is my client identifier and through the domain I get the information in the database and return the configured views to that client.

I configured the NGINX (minimum configuration) like this:

```
server {
      listen          80;
      server_name     domain1.example domain2.example domainn.com.br;
      root /opt/tomcat2/webapps/websites;

      location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/websitesapp;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


      }
}
```

Tomcat server.xml

```
<Context docBase="websitesapp" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:websitesapp"/>
```

In the application I retrieve the domain, and "mount" the a view with the information loaded from the database.

Is this setting correct?

Is there any way to pass the domain to tomcat more securely, ie without retrieving it by the browser's URL?

Is there any contraindication to this type of approach?

Any other approach that would be more interesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the `server_name`, these `server` blocks are otherwise identical. You can instead use a single `server` block with a `server_name` that lists all three domains. Or twenty, if you expand later...

The `$http_host` is OK to use, even though the browser provided it, because it has been validated. If it did not match one of the names in `server_name` in one of the `server` blocks, it would not have been used. (Provided you have a default `server`, which the default configuration has).

Comment: Actually I know they are identical, I put it this way just for dittal issues. My main question is whether this approach to getting domain through browser is a good approach. (the domain is my "key" to configure that client's site) I also thought of adding a new "header" including the domain, but I do not know how to do this in nginx. I do not have good knowledge of nginx.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It sounds like you are looking for trouble where none exists.